# Widgets are not displaying in my theme

Tags: widgets

I am getting one issue on my WordPress theme.

> Your theme has 2 other widget areas, but this particular page doesn’t display them. You can navigate to other pages on your site while using the Customizer to view and edit the widgets displayed on those pages.

I have a total number of 8 widgets on my widgets page and I added `Wordpress search widgets` in the `universal search widgets` but it's not displaying.

[image]

Then I checked `Appearance-> Customizeon` but It's displaying only 6.

[image]

Would you help me out how to solve this issue?
 I tried to check on google but I haven't found the solution.

**I am using below code**

```
/*universal search */
function universalSearch() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Universal Search',
        'id'            => 'universalSearchField',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'universalSearch' );

function universalSearch1() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Universal Search1',
        'id'            => 'universalSearch1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-newsletter">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-newsletter_title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'universalSearch1' );
```

**Displaying on page**

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar('universalSearchField')) : 
        dynamic_sidebar('universalSearchField');
        endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Id of register sidebar. i have tested and after changing id it is working fine. let me know if this solve you issue.

```
function universalSearch() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Universal Search',
        'id'            => 'universal-search-field',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

     register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Universal Search1',
        'id'            => 'universal-search-field-1',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-newsletter">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-newsletter_title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'universalSearch' );
```

**Displaying on page**

```
if ( is_active_sidebar('universal-search-field')) : 
    dynamic_sidebar('universal-search-field');
endif;

if ( is_active_sidebar('universal-search-field-1')) : 
    dynamic_sidebar('universal-search-field-1');
endif;
```

Comment: May I know why this answer got downvote?

Comment: I tried Id but same issue. I think I am not able to display more then 6 widget.

Comment: did you use these sidebar in particular page which you **Appearance-> customize**  ? because if you use sidebar in that page then only it will display in **Appearance-> customize**

Comment: I am trying to display on header.php and footer.php both page but it's not displaying. Event I am also using the ID name

Comment: did you saved widget after change id ? check here is there a search form in **Appearance-> widgets** https://prnt.sc/pz11zf ?  i have checked place code in header.php and footer.php and it is working

Comment: Give me sometime. Let me check again.

Comment: Yes, I check and it's working, I need to know what is the issue with my code. I am also using the ID

Comment: now working ?? may be issue is that you used capital characters in id.

Comment: Yes, it's capital characters in id. Thanks for the help